# reading null value in NUMBER variable using SELECT INTO query, but oracle is not considering it as null. what is the value present in the variable..?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Executing following block in Oracle Procedure

```
val NUMBER := 0;

BEGIN
  SELECT VALIDITY / 24
    INTO val
    FROM validity_table
   WHERE id = 123;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Validity : '||val);

   IF(val = NULL)
   THEN
      val := 0;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Validity : '||val);
   END IF;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
  THEN
     NULL;
END;
```

Output:

```
Validity :
```

in the validity_table value of the validity is null for the id 123 but while executing it, control is not going inside the if block. output is printed only once with no value. want to know what value the 'val' variable is containing.

Comment: `IF(val = NULL)` should be `IF val IS NULL`. Voting to close this as a typo.

Comment: `null` is not a value, so equality tests are always false.

Comment: @GMB - Not a typo, but a very common misunderstanding of how to test for NULL.  Should not have closed.

Comment: SELECT INTO will raise a no_data_found exception if there are no rows found, you need to test for that

Comment: A misunderstanding of how to process Null does not constitute a typo. It is one of the most misunderstood issued in RDBMS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not Oracle's (along with all other RDBMS, and the SQL Standard) consideration of Nulls, but your misunderstanding of them. Nulls actually introduce 3-valued logic: the result of any compassion may be true, false, or null. If this particular case the result the comparison (val=Null) is Null; since null is not true your if condition is not satisfied and therefore not processed. See [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f0b888e1d75345e7b09928eb4e0f358b) fiddle for comparisons involving Null.  
It's too bad Oracle has yet to see the benefits of boolean values in SQL. Guess they figure if it wasn't needed it 1979 why should it be needed in 2019 (after all how much can change in a mere 40 years)?